# Angular Validate field

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to validate the two fields such that the minimum value should be less than the maximum value. As the user types a value in the minimum score and if it is greater than the maximum score, error must be thrown.

```
<label class="col-2 col-form-label text-right font-weight-bold">Maximum Score*</label>
<div class="col-2">
  <input #firstScore="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="exams.firstScore" (keypress)="numberOnly($event)" name="firstScore" type="text">
</div>
<label class="col-3 col-form-label text-right font-weight-bold">Minimum Score*</label>
<div class="col-2">
  <input #secondScore="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="exams.secondScore" class="form-control" (keypress)="numberOnly($event)" name="secondScore" type="text"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
<label class="col-2 col-form-label text-right font-weight-bold">Maximum Score *</label>
<div class="col-2">
  <input #firstScore="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="exams.firstScore" (keypress)="numberOnly($event)" name="firstScore" type="text">
</div>
<label class="col-3 col-form-label text-right font-weight-bold">Manimum Score  *</label>
<div class="col-2">
  <input #secondScore="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="exams.secondScore" class="form-control" (keypress)="numberOnly($event)" name="secondScore" type="text"></div>
</div>
<span *ngIf="exams.secondScore > exams.firstScore">Your error message</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define a custom validator for this template-driven form so that the form itself fails to be submitted. Please look this [blog](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/custom-validator-in-template-driven-forms-in-angular/) to instruct how to make the custom validator. You can handle it better with reactive form instead of the template-driven one.